# Rails Partial error on refresh, not updating ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a car site as a project and having an odd issue. 
If I'm creating one car and adding items (via drop zone) and refreshing the partial with the images everything works great. Then I go to another car and the images load the correct ones for that car, but when I add another image to that car, the partial refreshes with the previous cars pictures instead of the current car.

Here's the Code in the Show page, referencing the partial:

```
<div id="links">
  <%= render partial: 'show', :object => @car %>
</div>
```

The script that Dropzone is using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
// disable auto discover
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;

var dropzone = new Dropzone (".dropzone", { 
maxFilesize: 400, // set the maximum file size to 256 MB
paramName: "image[extrapic]", // Rails expects the file upload to be something like model[field_name]
addRemoveLinks: true // don't show remove links on dropzone itself.
});

dropzone.on("success", function(file) {
this.removeFile(file);
$.getScript();
})
});
```

The code to refresh the partial:

```
$("#links").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('show')).html_safe %>");
```

And the partial itself:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
<% if image.car_id != nil && image.car_id == @car.id %>
    <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <%= link_to image_tag(image.extrapic.url(:thumb)), (image.extrapic.url(:large)) %>
        <% if can? :destroy, @car %>
            <br /><%= link_to 'Destroy', image,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this picture?' }, class: "btn btn-link" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated, I've tried a number of approaches, not quite sure where it's failing to update the @car.id, I assumed it would update when the page of the car loads, and does, until I add another image.

Comment: Do you have a github repo I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it finally, I had previously tried to use the Gon gem and it didn't work so I removed it, but I just added it back in and it's fine.

Apparently gon.watch doesn't work well if you place it in the head of he application.html.erb file, but if you move it down to the body of the letter it updates just fine. So I did that and added gon.watch.car_id = @car.id to the cars controller then in the javascript I called car.id in the script reference to update the partial and now it's all working!

Hopefully this will help someone else too!

d